# MySQL percona 5.6 to MySQL 5.5 replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, upgrade, percona-server

Scenario 1 I am having a MySQL DB on 5.5 which is compliance, So need to upgrade it to MySQL 5.6. while doing this we see that 5.6 is running slow, were as it runs perfectly on 5.5 backup.

Scenario 2 We have installed 5.6 percona MySQL on one system & just want to know if we can replicate on MySQL 5.5 using MySQL replication.

Please advice what issue will be faced in this 2 scenario. any suggestion is acceptable.

Comment: Replication should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you're asking in scenario 1.

As for scenario 2, you can have a slave that's a higher version than the master, but not vice-versa. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-compatibility.html):

> MySQL supports replication from one release series to the next higher release series. For example, you can replicate from a master running MySQL 5.5 to a slave running MySQL 5.6, from a master running MySQL 5.6 to a slave running MySQL 5.7, and so on.